# Sql Server Compact edition query error

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

There was an error parsing the query. `[ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 51,Token in error = select ]`

This is my query:

```
select * from SystemSettings where remainingtime=(select min(remainingtime)
from SystemSettings where remainingtime >=@available)
```

This query is working in Sql Server Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server CE does not support nested queries. Sorry.

Comment: Is there any embedded database supports nested queries?

Comment: There is MySQL, but it is infamous for its bad performance with subqueries. Why not use a temporary table?

Answer (score 0):

As noted here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417.aspx

Ms SQL Server CE 3.5 version supports nested queries but only in FROM clause, exmp. FROM=(select statement)